# Why does my program skip files when unzipping by java.util.zip?

Tags: java, zip

I read quite a few articles, but I did not find a similar problem and its solution.

**I'm try to read all files and some skipped with method zis.getNextEntry**

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String fileZip = "src/main/resources/unzipTest/fias_xml.zip";
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileZip));
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println(entry.getName());
            }
        }
}
```

**But if you unzip with WinRar, for example, everything will be unzipped correctly**

[Archive files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKrlM.png)

[After running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5N8I.png)

Or how i can see why some files doesn't read?

**Can the archive be broken?**

**After I unzipped and re-zipped the files by using winrar, the program worked correctly. Why was winrar able to do this, but the java code was not?**

[zipArchive](http://fias-file.nalog.ru/downloads/2021.03.02/fias_xml.zip)

**jdk1.8.0_161**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void unzip(String zipFile, String destDir)
    {
        try
        {
            int BUFFER = 8*1024;
            File file = new File(zipFile);
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
            String newPath = destDir;
            new File(newPath).mkdir();
            Enumeration zipFileEntries = zip.entries();
            while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements())
            {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
                String currentEntry = entry.getName();
                File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
                File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
                destinationParent.mkdirs();

                if (!entry.isDirectory())
                {
                    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip
                            .getInputStream(entry));
                    int currentByte;
                    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                    BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
                            BUFFER);
                    while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                        dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                    }
                    dest.flush();
                    dest.close();
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test i did i able to print each directory and file name correctly.

There 2 scenario came to my mind:
i) the filename length or the complete length is more what the platform can handle. But this also should be same case while do unzip from winrar
ii) Was there any permission issue, but again it won't be selective manner.

can you please let me which jdk version ?

Will u be able to sent me the zip file, I can try to simulate.

Comment: jdk1.8.0_161 https://fias-file.nalog.ru/downloads/2021.03.02/fias_xml.zip

Comment: Your using relative new version JDK should be fine, but the zip you attached in GigaByte :). How did you compare and get to the conclusion file is missing, maybe u missed some file. Anyway, i will simulate and see.

Comment: You can see image at the post "After running the program"

Comment: when i debug it seem like hanging and stopped. But I able to print:public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  
         String fileZip = <path>\\fias_xml.zip";   
     try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileZip)) {
             Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
             while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                 ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
   
   
   
 }

Comment: no flag at file. archive broken. now we use native method. Ty for yr help Wang Du!